# when i put a second section within an h2 this show up over the first section

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the `<h2>`of the second section is getting in the middle of the presentation and the first div. As you can see in the snippet below, the `<h2>` is showing over the first section of the html

```css
/* root stuff */
* {
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(2, 0, 5, 1) 12%,
    rgba(59, 7, 112, 1) 39%,
    rgba(83, 9, 168, 1) 100%
  );
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  /* padding-top: 70px; */
}
/* root stuff end */
/* nav bar stuff */
nav {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.493);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
/* nav bar stuff end */
/* welcome section stuff */
.welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
.picture-of-me {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
.subtitle-under-the-photo {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  .picture-of-me {
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  .subtitle-under-the-photo {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .picture-of-me {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subtitle-under-the-photo {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
/* skills stuff */
img {
  width: 2%;
}
.skills-container {
  max-width: 900%;
  padding: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.skills-presentation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}
.skills-presentation-left {
  width: 50%;
}
.skills-presentation-right {
  width: 10%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.photo-programming-skills-top {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .skills-container {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .skills-presentation-left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .skills-presentation-right {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .photo-programming-skills-top {
    margin-top: 5em;
  }
}
.skills-knowledge {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}
.skills-knowledge-right {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.photo-programming-skills-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.skills-knowledge-left {
  width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .skills-knowledge {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .skills-knowledge-left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .skills-knowledge-right {
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
  }
}
.container-lenguages {
  max-width: 900%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .container-lenguages {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
/* skills stuff end */
/* welcome section stuff end */
/* project section */
.project-section {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1067/1067357.svg"
    />
    <title>Alan Miranda</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#my-work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
      <h1>I'm Alan</h1>
      <img
        src="https://indiehoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/trent-reznor.jpg"
        alt="trent"
        class="picture-of-me"
      />
      <p class="subtitle-under-the-photo">
        a full stack developer and traveler from Argentina and the world. Scroll
        down and know me!
      </p>
      <div class="skills-container">
        <div class="skills-presentation">
          <div class="skills-presentation-left">
            <h3 class="my-skills">My Skills</h3>
            <p class="paragraph-programming-skills">
              I started to code when i was 27 years old, just for fun, to make
              games for my friends or websites for his personal profiles or
              stores and i started to think "well i do this for fun and i enjoy
              it, so why not give my time to build things for other people
              outside my circle?" and that was the way my journey started.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-presentation-right">
            <img
              src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/888/888954.svg"
              alt="photo of computer"
              class="photo-programming-skills-top"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-knowledge">
          <div class="skills-knowledge-right">
            <img
              class="photo-programming-skills-bottom"
              src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2942/2942789.svg"
              alt="web picture"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="skills-knowledge-left">
            <p class="paragraph-programming-skills">
              I'm a full stack developer, i'm highly experienced using the
              classical language like html, CSS and Javascript also frameworks
              like Bootstrap or libraries like Jquery, also i have experiences
              using Node.js, SQL, Express.js, building API's and in the last
              time i started to get more experience with my new love Python.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-lenguages">
          <h3 id="h3-of-languages">
            I don't only speak programming languages...
          </h3>
          <p id="p-of-languages">
            Living half of my life in different parts of the world help me to
            develop my communication skills, of course my native language is the
            spanish, but i'm also speaks english as my second and everyday
            language, also i´m advanced german speaker and a beginner in
            japanese.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section><h2>these are some of my works</h2></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hope the content of this code isn't something you're actually using

Answer (score 0):

the problem was `height: 100vh` in class `.welcome-section`

```css
/* root stuff */
* {
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    180deg,
    rgba(2, 0, 5, 1) 12%,
    rgba(59, 7, 112, 1) 39%,
    rgba(83, 9, 168, 1) 100%
  );
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  /* padding-top: 70px; */
}
/* root stuff end */
/* nav bar stuff */
nav {
  background: rgba(128, 0, 128, 0.493);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
}
/* nav bar stuff end */
/* welcome section stuff */
.welcome-section {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 100vh;*/
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
.picture-of-me {
  width: 25%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
.subtitle-under-the-photo {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  .picture-of-me {
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  .subtitle-under-the-photo {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .picture-of-me {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .subtitle-under-the-photo {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
/* skills stuff */
img {
  width: 2%;
}
.skills-container {
  max-width: 900%;
  padding: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.skills-presentation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}
.skills-presentation-left {
  width: 50%;
}
.skills-presentation-right {
  width: 10%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.photo-programming-skills-top {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .skills-container {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .skills-presentation-left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .skills-presentation-right {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .photo-programming-skills-top {
    margin-top: 5em;
  }
}
.skills-knowledge {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
}
.skills-knowledge-right {
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.photo-programming-skills-bottom {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.skills-knowledge-left {
  width: 50%;
}
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .skills-knowledge {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .skills-knowledge-left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .skills-knowledge-right {
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
  }
}
.container-lenguages {
  max-width: 900%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 790px) {
  .container-lenguages {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
/* skills stuff end */
/* welcome section stuff end */
/* project section */
.project-section {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="icon"
      href="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1067/1067357.svg"
    />
    <title>Alan Miranda</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li><a href="#welcome-section">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#my-work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="welcome-section" class="welcome-section">
      <h1>I'm Alan</h1>
      <img
        src="https://indiehoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/trent-reznor.jpg"
        alt="trent"
        class="picture-of-me"
      />
      <p class="subtitle-under-the-photo">
        a full stack developer and traveler from Argentina and the world. Scroll
        down and know me!
      </p>
      <div class="skills-container">
        <div class="skills-presentation">
          <div class="skills-presentation-left">
            <h3 class="my-skills">My Skills</h3>
            <p class="paragraph-programming-skills">
              I started to code when i was 27 years old, just for fun, to make
              games for my friends or websites for his personal profiles or
              stores and i started to think "well i do this for fun and i enjoy
              it, so why not give my time to build things for other people
              outside my circle?" and that was the way my journey started.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="skills-presentation-right">
            <img
              src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/888/888954.svg"
              alt="photo of computer"
              class="photo-programming-skills-top"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-knowledge">
          <div class="skills-knowledge-right">
            <img
              class="photo-programming-skills-bottom"
              src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2942/2942789.svg"
              alt="web picture"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="skills-knowledge-left">
            <p class="paragraph-programming-skills">
              I'm a full stack developer, i'm highly experienced using the
              classical language like html, CSS and Javascript also frameworks
              like Bootstrap or libraries like Jquery, also i have experiences
              using Node.js, SQL, Express.js, building API's and in the last
              time i started to get more experience with my new love Python.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-lenguages">
          <h3 id="h3-of-languages">
            I don't only speak programming languages...
          </h3>
          <p id="p-of-languages">
            Living half of my life in different parts of the world help me to
            develop my communication skills, of course my native language is the
            spanish, but i'm also speaks english as my second and everyday
            language, also i´m advanced german speaker and a beginner in
            japanese.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section><h2>these are some of my works</h2></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you going to explain your answer?

Comment: @j08691, there is a description of the problem at the beginning of the answer - the problem was height: 100vh in class .welcome-section

Comment: Well, now there is

Comment: Didn't help me but maybe the OP will like it

Comment: Those. do you do the same as i did in my answer and you still have the problem?